# Matplotlib and Latex with all bold

Tags: bold, matplotlib, labelling

I used to render all my Matplotlib fonts with latex and bold as follows:

```
plt.rc('font', family='serif',size=20)
matplotlib.rc('text', usetex=True)
matplotlib.rc('legend', fontsize=14) 
matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(16,8))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, right=0.94, top=0.94, bottom=0.08, 
                      wspace=0.08,hspace=0.20)
```

Unfortunately, this seems to not be working anymore. Here is my current result:

[image]

As you can notice all labels are not bold.
I have the following warning indeed:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Support for setting an rcParam that expects a str value to a non-str value is deprecated since 3.5 and support will be removed two minor releases later.
 matplotlib.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\boldmath']
```

I have tried different options but none of them seems to be working.

This is one example:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "sans-serif",
    "font.sans-serif": "Helvetica",
    'text.latex.preamble': r'\usepackage{bm}'
})
```

What do you think?  The following is from one of my old figures:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me (with python3.8):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('font', family='serif',size=20)
plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = r'\boldmath'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(16,8))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, right=0.94, top=0.94, bottom=0.18, 
                      wspace=0.08,hspace=0.20)


plt.xlabel(r'$\sigma\left(P^R_{d,t},W^M_{d,t}\right)$')
plt.show()
```

Here is the result. I have modified your bottom margin to have the axis label show up.
[image]